# How to mock a method call that takes a dynamic object

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, rhino-mocks

Say I have the following:

```
public interface ISession 
{
   T Get<T>(dynamic filter); }
}
```

And I have the following code that I want to test:

```
var user1 = session.Get<User>(new {Name = "test 1"});
var user2 = session.Get<User>(new {Name = "test 2"});
```

How would I mock this call?

Using Moq, I tired doing this:

```
var sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Get<User>(new {Name = "test 1")).Returns(new User{Id = 1});
sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Get<User>(new {Name = "test 1")).Returns(new User{Id = 2});
```

And that didn't work. The returned results is null

I also tried to do the following with Rhino Mocks:

```
var session = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISession>();
session.Stub(x => x.Get<User>(new {Name = "test 1"})).Return(new User{Id=1});
```

No luck either. Null again.

So how would I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `It.Is<object>` matcher together with reflection. You cannot use dynamic in expression trees so `It.Is<dynamic>` won't work that's why you need reflection to get the your property value by name:

```
sessionMock
    .Setup(x => x.Get<User>(
        It.Is<object>(d => d.GetPropertyValue<string>("Name") == "test 1")))
    .Returns(new User{Id = 1});
sessionMock
    .Setup(x => x.Get<User>(
        It.Is<object>(d => d.GetPropertyValue<string>("Name") == "test 2")))
    .Returns(new User { Id = 2 });
```

Where `GetPropertyValue` is a little helper:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return (T) obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Moq provided `It.IsAny<T>` for that case

```
sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Get<User>(It.IsAny<object>()).Returns(new User());
```

*dynamic is any object

Comment: Thanks ai.farfa. I cannot do that because I need to tell which object to return based on the different properties on the dynamic object

Answer (score 1):

First of all, anonymous objects are not really `dynamic`.

If you used `dynamic` objects like

```
dynamic user1Filter = new ExpandoObject();
user1Filter.Name = "test 1";
var user1 = session.Get<User>(user1Filter);
```

you could mock it like

```
sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Get<User>(DynamicFilter.HasName("test 1")));
```

by implementing custom argument matcher:

```
static class DynamicFilter
{
    [Matcher] public static object HasName(string name) { return null; }
    public static bool HasName(dynamic filter, string name)
    {
        string passedName = filter.Name; //dynamic expression
        return name.Equals(passedName);
    }
}
```