# Moq and methods with dynamic arguments

Tags: c#, dynamic, moq, verify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mock a method call that takes a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458714/how-to-mock-a-method-call-that-takes-a-dynamic-object)

I have a method with dynamic argument:

```
public void SampleMethod(dynamic arg) 
{ 
Console.WriteLine(arg.dynamicProperty);
}
```

Also I have a Moq mock for the class that contains this method.
I need to verify that SampleMethod was called so I tried the following code

`_dynClassMock.Verify(x => x.SampleMethod(It.IsAny<dynamic>()), Times.Once);`

but it doesn't work. I've the following compile time error:

An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: It.IsAny<object>() is too weak ?

Comment: Thanks Justin. My question duplicates that post.